# Entity Framework intercept and modify dates

Tags: entity-framework

I'm modifying a .Net web system that uses Entity Framework 6.2, the problem is that whenever a user enters a date, they do it in their local timezone. So what I thought was to intercept (IDbCommandInterceptor) all the inserts/updates, look for date fields and modify them to be UTC, then intercept all the requests (ReaderExecuted command) look for any date and adjust to the user local timezone.
So far no luck looking for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought was to intercept (IDbCommandInterceptor) all the inserts/updates, look for date fields and modify them to be UTC

I don't think that would work. You wouldn't be able to tell if a date value came from the user (local time) or from some other table, where it's already in UTC.  You need to handle this at a layer that understands what data is coming from the user or not.  IE not in a Command Interceptor, but in your Business Logic or View Model.